# Flash builder 4.7 compiles when there are errors to the latest error free version. Any way to avoid this?

Tags: flash, error-handling, flash-builder, builder

I'm fairly new to programming but there is a question I have about Flash builder 4.7 that I hope some of you can shed some light on.

Basically when I get a little error(like a typo) it seems like Fb 4.7 compiles to the last error free version.

This is really annoying because I might continue programming thinking everything is fine. Then when I test my program I don't get the result I thought I would get.

At one occasion I tried to solve a problem for about an hour only to figger out I got it right the first time and the only reason the program wouldn't work like I intended was because of a typo in one of the Class files.

Any way around this? Any settings i can reset in Flash builder 4.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple using the Flash Builder Editor preferences.

Go to `Window > Preferences` (or `Flash Builder > Preferences under OSX`), then choose `Flash Builder > Editors`.  Make sure "`Report problems as you type`" is checked.

Look at the `Run/Debug > Launching` preferences, too.  Make sure that `Continue launch of project contains errors` is set to `Prompt`.

You can also turn off `Build Automatically` in the `Project` menu.  You'll have to explicitly build your project, and it will give you a message that the build failed if there was a problem.